# Exported databases have different sizes

Tags: mysql

If I export a database with phpmyadmin his size is 18MB

If I expoert it from terminal using this command is size is only 11MB.

/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u root -ppassword ${DB} | gzip > ${DB}.sql.gz

Could you explain me why ? Is because of --otp parameter ?

How can I be sure the database has been succesfully exported ? Should I inspect it.. still it is not a reliable evaluation. thanks

Comment: Just a dumb question: Is your phpmyadmin dump compressed as well?

Comment: prefer mysqldump, far better dumps, trust me, at least they knwo how to order inserts when you have dependencies, so can you can import the dump -- and what is a dump you vannot import...

Comment: @regilero Yeah I'm going to use mysqldump indeed. But how to be sure it worked correctly ? Probably just because it is the first time and I'm a bit scared. And yes, it was the same compression, anyway I'm comparing the extracted sql files.

Comment: @regilero: you can always disable foreign key checks during an import, making the import order irrelevant.

Comment: @Marc B : or you can use mysqldump and avoid adding tricks to get around issues :-)

Comment: Just check # tail dumpfile.sql should give you something like # -- Dump completed on 2011-01-11 10:17:24

Comment: @shantanuo and @regilero and @Marc B If I import the dumped database (exported using mysqldump) with phpmyadmin and export it again using phpmyadmin, I get the original size (6mb more). So I guess it is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the details you've given, there are a number of possibilties as to why the sizes may differ. Assuming the output from phpMyAdmin is also gzipped (otherwise the obvious reason for the difference would be that one is compressed, the other isn't), the following could affect size to some degree:

- Different ordering of INSERT statements causing differences in the compressibility of the data
- One using extended inserts, the other using only standard inserts (this seems most likely given the difference in sizes).
- More comments added by the phpMyAdmin export tool
- etc...

I'd suggest looking at the export to determine completeness (perhaps restore it to a test database and verifying that the row-counts on all tables are the

Comment: No it is not because of compression, I'm comparing the sql file. So the evaluation you suggest is to check the number of rows. Is there any automatic tool to compare 2 sql files and find out if the data is the same ?

Comment: Different gzip levels as well. One could be zipping for speed, one for space

Comment: So in the end, I've imported the smaller database into phpmyadmin and exported it again and.. magic it is 17MB again.. so it is complete and I assume everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment so I'm adding my comments in this answer...

If you look at the uncompressed contents of the export files from a phpmyadmin export and a mysqldump they will be quite different.

You could use diff to compare the two sql files:

`diff file1.sql file2.sql`

However, in my experience that will NOT be helpful in this case.

You can simply open the files in your favorite editor and compare them to see for yourself.

As mentioned by Iridium in the previous answer, the use of inserts can be different. I created two new empty databases and imported into each (via phpmyadmin) - one of the two exports mentioned above (one from phpmyadmin and the other via mysqldump).

The import using the mysqldump export file recreated the database containing 151 tables with 1484 queries.

The import using the phpmyadmin export file recreated the database containing 151 tables with 329 queries.

Of course these numbers apply only to my example, but it seems to be in line what Iridium was talking about earlier.